# Is it possible to have scala Future execute a mapping action in the same thread, like Java CompletableFuture?

Tags: multithreading, scala, future

In Java it is possible to do:

```
CompletableFuture<Integer> e = new CompletableFuture<Integer>();
e = e.thenApply(x -> x * 2);
e.complete(12);
```

in this scenario the function in `thenApply` will run in the thread that is calling `e.complete` see [thenApply](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#thenApply-java.util.function.Function-)

In Scala I noticed that all manipulation functions for the future have an ExecutionContext as argument, so I assume [map](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.9.3/scala/concurrent/Future.html#map) (that does the same as thenApply) will send another task to the execution context.

How can I get the same behaviour of a Java CompletableFuture with non Async methods?

Comment: Unless you notice some perf issue, why being concerned about? (premature optim ...)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is possible in priciple. In fact, scala's `ExecutionContext` -- as opposed to java's thread pools -- abstracts over where you code is run and doesn't force you to schedule it on a thread of a certain thread pool. Instead, it could as well be the current thread. This is typically referred to as a *tramplined execution context*.

For example the play framework defines one: https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/38abd1ca6d17237950c82b1483057c5c39929cb4/framework/src/play-streams/src/main/scala/play/api/libs/streams/Execution.scala#L31

However, before implementing this, you should really be sure you know what you're doing and you really need this. In fact, the play framework has decided not to expose it, because it's too easy to shoot in one's foot with it:

> So... given that trampoline is not widely known and won't lead to performance advantages for users, closing.

Source: https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/6390

A similar discussion happened on the scala-interals mailing list, where the debate was whether to add one to the scala standard library. In the end, the reservations were similar:

> We have hesitated in exposing it as a general thing since it can *very easily* wreak having for *synchronous implementations*.

Source: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/scala-internals/QgtKugpqUlk/llVXveEuFAAJ

Also note that there are alternative implementations that might help if you're writing performance-sensitive / concurrent code, such as monix: https://monix.io/api/3.0/

Comment: I don't understand the claim "won't lead to performance advantages for users". I can think of lots of scenarios where it will be a great deal more efficient. Yes it can lead to deadlocks if people are not careful, but this would be an advanced feature anyhow. .NET and java both do this for performance reasons.

Comment: I guess what he meant was that you really need to your know your doing otherwise the benefit might not be worth the price.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @rethab, after having a look at your pointers, and looking the default implementation of ExecutionContext, I found a very simple solution:

```
object MyExCont extends ExecutionContext {
    override def execute(runnable: Runnable): Unit = runnable.run()

    override def reportFailure(cause: Throwable): Unit = cause.printStackTrace()
  }


  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val p = Promise[String]()
    val e = p.future

    val t = new Thread(()=>{
      LOGGER.info("Completing")
      p.complete(Try {
        "hello"
      })
    })

    val f = e.map(x => {
      LOGGER.info("Adding...")
      x + ";"
    }, MyExCon)

    Thread.sleep(10)
    t.start()
    LOGGER.info(Await.result(f, Duration.Inf))
  }
```

this will result in either:

1. If the future is not complete at the time of e.map(...), then the thread when Promise.complete is called will run the mapping operation
2. If the futures is complete at the time of e.map(...), then it is the thrad where e.map is run that will undertake the work.